# Finding past depedencies of a package

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I am looking into finding the past dependencies of certain packages. I know that in order to get the current ones I can use `apt-cache depends packagename`. However, this only gives me the current dependencies from what I understood. I am mainly looking for a list of dependencies per version release of a package. Is there a way to find those?

Comment: The package itself includes dependency information for its current version, and that's where apt gets the information from. Neither apt nor the package store historical data. For an older version, you must review the debian control file included in that older version. For multiple older versions, you must review each control file in each older version. Changelogs might have some of the information you seek.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Could you maybe tell me where I can find older Debian control files? Do I need to download older versions of the same package? I have also already looked into the changelogs, but I was only able to find the release date and the release number, aside from some comments.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. You could read/process the changelogs for a package to see when dependency on a particular library was added. Internet search "Ubuntu changelogs".